# Можно ли при наследовании класса выполнить какой-то код?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вот есть класс

```
class A:
    initialize = False
```

Есть другой класс

```
class B(A):
    initialize = True
```

Так вот мне нужно, если наследуется класс от класса A и initialize = True выполнить определенный код, так сказать __init__только как classmethod

Comment: На каком этапе надо выполнить какие-то действия? На этапе создания экземпляра?

Comment: Нет, если при создании экземпляра, можно обойтись __init__ методом, мне нужно при инициализации класса.

Comment: Но вы же сами явно указываете, от какого класса наследуетесь, зачем выполнять проверку? Или пример не полный, и речь идет о метапрограммировании?

Comment: Хм, я о метаклассах как-то не знал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MyMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        print(f"{name}, initialize={attrs['initialize']}")

        if attrs['initialize']:
            attrs['SUPER_VALUE'] = 42
            attrs['run'] = lambda self=None: print('run!')

        attrs['reverse_initialize'] = not attrs['initialize']

        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)


class A(metaclass=MyMeta):
    initialize = False


class B(A):
    initialize = True


print(hasattr(A, 'SUPER_VALUE'))  # False
print(hasattr(B, 'SUPER_VALUE'))  # True
print()

print(A.initialize, A.reverse_initialize)  # False True
print(B.initialize, B.reverse_initialize)  # True False
print()

print(B.SUPER_VALUE)  # 42
B.run()               # run!

b = B()
print(b.SUPER_VALUE)  # 42
b.run()               # run!
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте метаклассы:

```
class A(object):
    initialize = False


def class_init(class_name, class_parent, class_attr):
    if class_attr.get('initialize'):
        print('Do some init code with class %s' % class_name)
    else:
        print('Do not any code with class %s' % class_name)
    return type(class_name, class_parent, class_attr)


class B(A, metaclass=class_init):
    initialize = True


class C(A, metaclass=class_init):
    pass
    # Наследует initialize = False из родительского класса
```

Код выведет:

```
Do some init code with class B
Do not any code with class C
```